# Meaning of "Nobody thought we had a chance entering this season"

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjuncts

> Nobody thought we had a chance entering this season

would be understood as:

A) Nobody thought we had a chance when we entered this season
B) Nobody thought we had a chance to enter this season

What would be the correct one?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, except for missing a period. They have different meaning.

Comment: Hi Dan, yeah, but if as it stands and understands as A, I wouldn’t really get the meaning for “ Nobody thought we had a chance”, a chance for what? I don’t quite get it.

Comment: "It _is understood_ as A". Presumably the sentence refers to a sports team, so "a chance of winning the tournament or doing well in it".

Answer (score 3):

As it stands, it would probably be understood as A, meaning "Nobody thought we had a chance [while] entering this season," that is, the final phrase becomes participular. If you added the word *of* you'd get the second meaning: "Nobody thought we had a chance **of** entering this season," meaning "a chance to enter."

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you so much for your comment, yeah I get your point but it’s a bit confusing as “Nobody had a chance” wouldn’t be clear in that case. Like “a chance for what”? It’s not really understandable.

Comment: @DennisNguyen Yes; as with most things, meaning depends on context. You've given a single sentence with no context. If a stranger blurted it to you on the street and then walked away, it would have no meaning. If it were used in a discussion, then earlier sentences would probably have made the meaning more clear. For that matter, what does "we" refer to? The antecedent must be in the preceding context.